# error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, image, button, video, onclick

I have this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type
> 'NodeListOf

Here is my code:

**HTML:** (it's a element of my portafolio and I want to play a video on click)

```
<div>
  <img id="todolist" src="assets/images/todolistCapture.png" alt="restaurant pascal"/>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h4>Todo list</h4>
    <p style="font-size: 12px; margin: 0 50px;"> Todo list with React</p>
    <div id="btn" class="btn activ animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft animate__delay-2s">
      <div class="play"></div>
      <p>Play video</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-portafolio',
    templateUrl: './portafolio.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./portafolio.component.css'],
})
export class PortafolioComponent {


    constructor() {
        const button = document.querySelectorAll('#btn');
        const close = document.querySelectorAll('#close');
        const videoContent = document.querySelectorAll('#videoContent');

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            videoContent.style.visibility = 'visible';
            videoContent.style.opacity = 1;
        });

        close.addEventListener('click', () => {
            videoContent.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            videoContent.style.opacity = 0;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not a expert, but i want to learn typescript, and I don't understand where is my error(s).

**tsconfig.json:**

```
"target": "ES2022",
"module": "ES2022",
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` is used to select multiple elements.
For a single element, you should use `querySelector`.

The output type of `querySelectorAll` in TypeScript is `NodeListOf<Element>`, while the output of `querySelector` in JavaScript is an `Element or null`.

In TypeScript, it is typed as `Element | null`.

And on `Element`, you have style attribute.

Comment: hi Eden, thank you for your answer. and your patience

Comment: You're welcome !
If you find this answer useful, you can upvote it and approve the answer for this thread.